# Checking of current system date in static table

Tags: oracle, function, date, stored-procedures, plsql

I am new to pl/sql blocks..i have a requirement inside my proc as below:

I have a static data table `tb_calender` having column `extract_date` with `DATE` type. Want to check if the current system date is present in the table `tb_calender.extract_date` . If not present, exit the proc with logging error.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 2):

A function might be more appropriate (so that you'd let the caller know whether today's date exists in the table or not). You could return a Boolean, or e.g. a number (which is simpler as you can use it in SQL, while Boolean *works* only in PL/SQL).

You probably don't want to check `sysdate` itself as it contains date AND time components (up to seconds), so ... how probable is it that table contains a value which matches *right now*? That's why I used `TRUNC` function.

Setup:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from tb_calender;

EXTRACT_DATE
-------------------
10.01.2022 00:00:00        --> that's today's date
08.01.2022 00:00:00

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
10.01.2022 20:34:42
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test_01
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    /* Return 1 if EXTRACT_DATE which is equal to today's date exists.
  5       Return 0 otherwise
  6    */
  7    l_cnt number;
  8  begin
  9    select count(*)
 10      into l_cnt
 11      from tb_calender
 12      where extract_date = trunc(sysdate);
 13
 14    return case when l_cnt = 0 then 0
 15                else 1
 16           end;
 17  end f_test_01;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test_01 from dual;

 F_TEST_01
----------
         1
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2  is
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from tb_calender
  8      where extract_date = trunc(sysdate);
  9
 10    if l_cnt = 0 then
 11       dbms_output.put_line('Today''s date does not exist');
 12    else
 13       dbms_output.put_line('Today''s date exists');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_test;
Today's date exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```